# css filters on svg elements not applied in safari

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to apply a simple css filter to elements in a svg.
This works very well in all browsers except Safari. The filters are not applied there.
Is it basically not possible to apply css filter to svg element in Safari? Or am I making a mistake?
I know I could use svg-filter. In my specific case, this is unfortunately not a solution.

```css
svg{
  width: 200px;
  /*   filter here works in safari */
  /* filter: blur(5px); */
}

#circle{
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#square{
  filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px 4px #4444dd);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 187.7 106.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 187.7 106.3;" xml:space="preserve">
<rect id="square" x="20.2" y="20" style="fill:#E30613;" width="66.7" height="66.7"/>
<circle id="circle" style="fill:#6AB42D;" cx="134.1" cy="53.4" r="33.4"/>
</svg>
```

Result in Safari:

[image]

Result in other Browsers:

[image]

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246106

Comment: Known Issues: In Safari filter won't apply to child elements while they are animating. 
Currently there are no browsers with support for spread-radius in the drop-shadow filter. 
In Edge filter won't apply if the element or its parent has negative z-index. [check Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=filter%3A%20blur)

Comment: @stax for spread-radius [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#funcdef-filter-drop-shadow) would need to be updated first.

Comment: [@RobertLongson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) I would accept your comment as the correct answer:
Currently it is not possible to apply css filter to svg elements in Safari because of a bug in webkit. Maybe you want to make it an answer.